# Coverage toolbox missing from "System Toolboxes"

Tags: arcgis

As could be seen from the following screenshot, the "Coverage" toolbox is missing from the list of "System Toolboxes" in ArcCategolog view.

Link to screenshots: (a dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ww00wskdci39ph5/AAD-hRUtLWui31dASOOZYfP_a?dl=0)

Awaiting suggestions on how to recover this toolbox. (The directory to this tool have been suggested by the search window, where the tool "Add XY Coordinates" is of particular interest.)

Thank you.

Version of ArcDesktop: 10.2.2

Comment: I think this question would be better asked at [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com)  where it could be migrated if you flag a moderator to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Coverage Tools** toolbox is only available if you have ArcInfo Workstation installed and licensed.  You may need to repair the Desktop install if you installed Workstation after Desktop.  See this thread for more info:

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1727&t=131314